# How to replicate a WordPress-styled table in the admin area

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin for WordPress and I need to emulate the functionality (and style) of a WP table for the admin area. I mean those basic tables that appear on any menu page, like the ones that list the Pages or the Comments.

I've made some progress on that: I've managed to replicate the WP style by simply using the same CSS classes and HTML that they use in their own tables, but I'm not sure this is the right way to approach this.
I actually only need the pagination and filter functionalities, nothing else. I guess I can put my own logic here and get it done, but I was wondering if there was a simpler, more appropriate way to do this.

So, any thoughts on how **should** I build a table in the admin area of WordPress so that it matches the style/functionality of the default ones?

(BTW, I'm not using a Custom Post Type, just a custom top-level admin menu. Hence the need for a table made from scratch.)

Here's the code I'm using to display my custom admin page (there are some literal values for simplicity):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h1><?= $helper->esc_html__(get_admin_page_title()) ?></h1>

    <hr class="wp-header-end">
    <br>

    <form>
        <div class="tablenav top">
            <div class="alignleft actions">
                <label for="filter-by-date" class="screen-reader-text">Filter by date</label>

                <select name="filter-by-date">
                    <option value="all" selected>All dates</option>
                    <option value="last-month">Last month</option>
                    <option value="last-week">Last week</option>
                    <option value="today">Today</option>
                </select>

                <input type="submit" name="filter-action" class="button" value="Filter">
            </div>

            <div class="tablenav-pages">
                <?php
                    // translators: %d: Total number of elements
                    $elements_count = sprintf($helper->esc_html__('%d elements'), $requests_count);
                ?>

                <span class='displaying-num'><?= $elements_count ?></span>

                <span class="pagination-links">
                    <span class="tablenav-pages-navspan" aria-hidden="true">«</span>

                    <a class="prev-page" href="#">
                        <span class="screen-reader-text">Previous page</span>
                        <span aria-hidden="true">‹</span>
                    </a>

                    <span class="paging-input">
                        <label for="current-page-selector" class="screen-reader-text">Current page</label>
                        <input type="text" name="paged" id="current-page-selector" class="current-page" value="2" size="1" aria-describedby="table-paging">
                        <span class="tablenav-paging-text"> of <span class="total-pages">3</span></span>
                    </span>

                    <a class="next-page" href="#">
                        <span class="screen-reader-text">Next page</span>
                        <span aria-hidden="true">›</span>
                    </a>

                    <span class="tablenav-pages-navspan" aria-hidden="true">»</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="manage-column column-primary"><?= $helper->esc_html__('Movie Title') ?></th>
                <th class="manage-column"><?= $helper->esc_html__('Release') ?></th>
                <th class="manage-column"><?= $helper->esc_html__('Language') ?></th>
                <th class="manage-column"><?= $helper->esc_html__('User') ?></th>
                <th class="manage-column"><?= $helper->esc_html__('Date') ?></th>
                <th class="manage-column"><?= $helper->esc_html__('Actions') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="the-list">
            <!-- If there are any requests, display each record, otherwise, inform the user -->
            <?php if ($requests_count): ?>
                <?php foreach ($requests as $request): ?>
                          <tr class="is-expanded">
                              <td class="column-primary" data-colname="Movie Title">
                                  <strong><?= $helper->esc_html__($request->title) ?></strong>
                              </td>

                              <td data-colname="Release">
                                  <?php if ($request->release === null): ?>
                                      <span class="sr-text-info"><?= $helper->esc_html__('Not Specified') ?></span>
                                  <?php else: ?>
                                      <?= esc_html($request->release); ?>
                                  <?php endif; ?>
                              </td>

                              <td data-colname="Language"><?= $helper->esc_html__($request->language) ?></td>

                              <td data-colname="User">
                                  <?php if ($request->user === null): ?>
                                      <span class="sr-text-info"><?= $helper->esc_html__('Anonimous') ?></span>
                                  <?php else: ?>
                                      <?= esc_html($request->user); ?>
                                  <?php endif; ?>
                              </td>

                              <td data-colname="Date">
                                  <?php
                                      $date = new DateTime($request->date);

                                      // translators: draft request date format, see http://php.net/date
                                      $request_date_fmt = $helper->__('m/d/Y, g:i a');

                                      echo esc_html($date->format($request_date_fmt));
                                  ?>
                              </td>

                              <td data-colname="Actions">
                                  <a class="button" href="#">Delete</a>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                      <tr class="is-expanded">
                          <td class="sr-text-center" colspan="6">
                              <span class="sr-text-info"><?= $helper->esc_html__('There are no requests to show.') ?></span>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about using iframe?

Comment: No, that would be an unnecessary overhead, and it's not the way WP deals with this when displaying tables in the admin area. I'm not even sure I should be building it from scratch in the first place. There's a class that generates admin tables, but it depends on other stuff and I'm not sure I can instantiate it just like that. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option is to `extend` the native [`WP_List_Table`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) class which is already available in WordPress Core. While this *is* a private class in core, it probably won't change drastically in the future and I would personally consider it safe to extend.

When you define your own class and extend `WP_List_Table`, all you'll need to do is create your own methods with the logic for the data. The best part is that the parent `WP_List_Table` class will handle **everything** else for you (markup, styles, pagination, etc).

[WP Engineer](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/) has a good beginner's guide to get you started. You can also search the web for "WP_List_Table guide", "WP_List_Table tutorial", (etc) and you'll find plenty of examples online.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Jared, for your answer. I had a feeling I should've been using the WP_List_Table class, just wasn't sure how. I'll try this out right away, also check on the links, and get back here. Thanks again.

Comment: An excellent approach, and the resources you shared are beyond good. I was looking for an appropriate (more humane) way to do this and couldn't find a specific, concise answer. BTW, the WP Codex states that WP_List_Table class is subject to change, but they still consider it the best way to go for this, like you said. However they think it's a good practice to copy the whole class, put it in your plugin and the extend from there. Just a safety measure. Thanks again @Jared.